# Boosting documents when the numeric search value lands between two fields of the document

Tags: solr, solr4

Is there a way to boost documents that for a search query A, A lands beween  field X and field Y? but just boost them , I don't want to filter the non-matches

I know that if I would like to filter I could go the route:

```
fieldX:[* TO A] AND fieldY:[A TO *]
```

but I don't want to filter, I just want to boost these documents, the documents which A is not between X and Y should still be considered just rank lower.

Its a custom function the way to go?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a version of Solr up to 4.9, you can use [ReRanking](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Query+Re-Ranking) by doing a query like :

```
q=yourRequest&rq={!rerank reRankQuery=$rqq reRankDocs=1000 reRankWeight=3}&rqq=(fieldX:[* TO A] AND fieldY:[A TO *])
```

This will reRank your first 1000 documents using your subquery.